# Session not destroying in AdonisJs

Tags: adonis.js

in a web app we have used 2 Auth methods
default is JWT which we are using for API’s
but for website we are using session
somehow session are not destroying on logout
i can still access session by

```
auth.authenticator('session').getUser()
```

even after this doing in logout

```
await auth.authenticator('session').logout()
```

Here is my full code for login

```
Route.get('/login', async ({ view ,auth,response}) => {
  try{
   await auth.authenticator('session').check()
    response.route('/feed')
  } 
  catch(e){
    return view.render('user.login') // User login page in web
  }  
})
```

Logout route

```
Route.get('/logout', async ({ auth, response }) => {
  await auth.authenticator('session').logout()
  response.route('/login')
})
```

*i have noticed that if i disable chrome cache from dev tools then web app works fine*

[image]